# Clarification needed on registering components in Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, ioc-container

According to [documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-by-conventions&NS=Windsor) I'm trying to register all my IRepository implementations for further injecting in controllers like that:

```
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IRepository>()
                .WithService.Base()
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

Usage of concrete repository instances is straightforward:

```
public class TheController : Controller
{
    private MyConcreteRepository repo;


    public TheController (MyConcreteRepository r)
    {
        repo = r;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ans = repo.GiveMeData<TheDataType>();
        ...
        ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

And starting the application it throws

```
'MyMVCWebSite.Controllers.TheController' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'MyMVCWebSite.DataUtils.MyConcreteRepository' which was not registered.
```

Repositories hierarchy looks like

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    ...
}


public interface IAlmostConcreteRepository : IRepository
{
    DbSet<TEntity> GiveMeData<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}


public class MyConcreteRepository : IAlmostConcreteRepository 
{
    protected DbContext context;

    public MyConcreteRepository(DbContext dbc)
    {
        context = dbc;
    }

    public DbSet<TEntity> GiveMeData<TEntity>() where TEntity : class 
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So neither [registering components one-by-one](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx)

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IAlmostConcreteRepository>()
            .ImplementedBy<MyConcreteRepository>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
```

nor doing that by conventions as mentioned at begining of the post don't work.
Only concrete instances can be registered:

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<MyConcreteRepository>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
```

or

```
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(MyConcreteRepository))
                .WithService.Base()
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

Did I miss something in documentation? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have used MyConcreteRepository class instead of interface, so that was the problem.

```
public class TheController : Controller
{
    private MyConcreteRepository repo;


    public TheController (MyConcreteRepository r)
    {
        repo = r;
    }
}
```

Simple misspeled, should be:

```
public class TheController : Controller
{
    private IAlmostConcreteRepository repo;


    public TheController (IAlmostConcreteRepository r)
    {
        repo = r;
    }
}
```